# Prevent the automatic indent on lines starting with expression

Tags: emacs, indentation

I'm using emacs, but I'm having a problem with the setting for indents.

Whenever I start a line with `#`, it automatically indents the line.  I don't want this to happen.

Can I configure this behavior?  How can I do this?

Comment: As suggested below, we need to know the major mode you're using. Please use the **edit** link at the bottom-left of your question to update it with this information.

Answer (score 1):

Each major mode has its own indenting behavior, so in general you need to know which major mode you're using (`C-h v major-mode` or `C-h m`), and the way to change the behavior is major mode dependent.

However, I'm going to guess that this is `electric-indent-mode` (`C-h f electric-indent-mode`).  You can toggle it with `M-x electric-indent-mode` or `M-x electric-indent-local-mode`, or customize its variables.

Comment: yes i'm using electric-indent-mode , how do i prevent it from indenting lines starting with certain words

Comment: The major mode is possibly still relevant, what is it?  Does the undesirable behavior go away if you turn off `electric-indent-mode`?

Comment: It's probably not `electric-indent-mode` then.  Why won't you post the major mode?

Comment: the mode is verilog mode

Comment: I'm not very familiar with verilog mode.  When I switch the major mode to verilog mode and type "#", it does not indent.  Try running Emacs like `emacs -q` to prevent it from loading your settings.  If it behaves the way you want with `-q`, bisect your init.el to find the setting that makes it misbehave.